# jQuery popover won't work in Django application?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I'm trying to add in a very simple bit of JavaScript into my Django template but the popover just doesn't seem to work.

This is my current configuration and file structure

django-jquery installed with 'jquery'  in installed apps.

**settings.py**

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

**myapp/static/js/jquery.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

**home.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1> Home </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="Content in here">Click to toggle popover</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Button when clicked doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions helpful! Thanks

Comment: `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in the src is not the way to get the static folder, check the result in the generated source code. You can try `{% static "myapp/js/jquery.js" %}` instead

Comment: use your browser dev tools to check for errors, you'll see a 404 error for not being able to load your script, as PRMoureu mentioned. Also looking at your js path, it's `{% static "js/jquery.js" %}` without the `myapp`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I followed  via documentation([django-jquery](https://pypi.org/project/django-jquery/)) to which used `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in the syntax but I've change it to `{% static "js/jquery.js" %}` . Using the dev tools (inspect), I can see that when I select the button it loads a div below with data relating to the button but does not load anything in the view.

Comment: But what's the **url** you have in your HTML for the `src` attribute?

Comment: by the way, I wouldn't use django-query. It's old, the documentation is not up-to-date. Just use plain jQuery, it's just javascript, no need to package it for django.

Comment: Also I don't understand your jquery.js file, your own code should be in a different file, the jquery.js file is the one you download from the web. What is `popover()` function supposed to do? Where is it defined?